# what does dividing an image into 64 x 36 uniform grid mean?

Tags: image-processing

I also want to know will there be overlap between the vertices of the grid cells obtained in the process?
Will there be a common edge?

EDIT: Actually I am using a 1280 x 720 image and dividing into the gridform.
This will create 20 x 20 pixel blocks.

Answer (score 2):

A uniform grid is simply a grid constructed by rows and columns that are of equal size. So the area of the square section found at position (i, j) is the same area as at every other position in the grid.

This grid will be 64 squares in width, by 36. I pressume if you're doing image processing then this is about dividing the image into sections of 64 by 36 pixels. (Pixels are of course uniform in size.)